# Instantiating an object via a string name and calling

Tags: c#, winforms, object

I have a problem and am unable to solve this; I would appreciate some help.
So, I have created a WinForm that contains a 'Person' class with its methods and properties along with a constructor:

```
public Person(string givenName, string givenAddress)
{
    name = givenName;
    address = givenAddress;
}
```

I would like to create an instance of class with an input string from a textbox and call its methods `.setName(txtName.text)` and `.setAddress(txtAddress.text)` at a later stage.

Each object created from 'Person' would be stored within a list

```
List<Person> listPerson = new List<Person>();
```

How may I call the specific object name and its method later, and how may I create an object via an input string?

Comment: Please explain what do you mean with _create an object via an input string_

Comment: Where a user inputs text into a textbox. This value will then be used to create an object. E.g. Person textbox (however this will not work, obviously).

Comment: So if the user types "Person" you wish to create an instance of the class Person right? But what about the properties Name and Address? The instance created in this way will be empty

Comment: That was the problem I was having.

Answer (score 3):

You may start by reading a beginner C# book or Tutorial (dozens available online):

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { set; get; } // property with auto setter and getter
    public string Address { set; get; } // property with auto setter and getter

   public Person(string givenName, string givenAddress)
   {
        Name = givenName;
        Address = givenAddress;
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Person> listPerson = new List<Person>();
var person1 = new Person(textBoxName.Text, textBoxAddress.Text);
listPerson.Add(person1);

string name = person1.Name; // get name
string address = person1.Address; // get address
```

Comment: @JLe `textBoxName.Text` and `textBoxAddress.Text` are the input string sample read from UI controls.

Comment: How may I store multiple objects within listPerson via different strings as its var name?

Comment: @JLe This is very basic OOP question, i think you need to get a Tutorial. It is as simple as copying that line and using another unique identifier. `var person2 = ....` and then `listPerson.Add(person2);`. It is as simple as that.